# Build a nested list of lines from a text file in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, file, import

I have a text file called "a_file.txt". I want to put all words from this file into a nested list called my_list. For some reason, the code below does not work, i.e. my_list is an empty list. How come is it possible and how would you do to solve my problem?

```
file_opened=open('a_file.txt')
my_list=[]
for line in file_opened:
    words=line.split()
    my_list.append(words)

print my_list
```

Comment: Sounds like the file is empty. Show us the result of `print(file_opened.read())`.

Comment: `for line in file_opened.readlines()` ?

Comment: empty or full of whitespace. That's the only explanation.

Comment: print(file_opened.read()) is empty as well. But the 'words' list contains the words of the last line. So I guess my file is not empty

Comment: can you open the file in some text editor? And do you see any content in that?

Comment: and if running on ipython or shell reopen the file. As if you're not running the whole script the file_object is having cursor at the end of file.

Comment: yeah i do see contents. There is something i miss but I do not get what.

Comment: ok I got it, there was a cursor at the end of file!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, as harshil9968 suggests, I had a cursor at the end of file. Once I removed it. It does work. Thks guys!!

Comment: please don't post an answer which is not an answer.